# TinyMCE: Can you embed a plugin in a custom menu button?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

Working from this codepen
http://codepen.io/tinymce/pen/NGegZK

Code:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 500,
  theme: 'modern',
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image hr anchor media table',
    'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker imagetools'
  ],
  toolbar1: 'bold italic formatting | fontsizeselect forecolor backcolor removeformat | format bullist numlist outdent indent | table link  emoticons',
  image_advtab: true,
  menubar: false,
  templates: [
    { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
    { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
  ],

    setup: function(editor) {
    editor.addButton('formatting', {
      type: 'menubutton',
      text: '',
      icon: true,
      image: 'http://www.veryicon.com/icon/16/System/iOS7%20Minimal/Text%20Formatting%20Border%20color.png',
      menu: [{
        text: 'Make me font size select!',
        }
      }, {
        text: 'Forecolor etc',
      }]
    });
  }, 
  content_css: [
    '//fast.fonts.net/cssapi/e6dc9b99-64fe-4292-ad98-6974f93cd2a2.css',
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
  ]
 });
```

Notice the 3rd item is a custom formatting menu (looks like a crayon)

**What I want to do is embed the fontsizeselect forecolor backcolor removeformat plugins into that menu.**

Do I need to rebuild all the plugins from scratch? It seems like they should be usable in a menu, shouldn't they?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Glen -

As you appear to have surmised the code that adds these default behaviors to the toolbar is done in various plugins (and in some cases the main TinyMCE JS file).

For example...

- `forecolor` and `backcolor` are added via the `textcolor` plugin.
- `fontsizeselect` and `removeformatting` are added in the main `tinymce.js` file.

This (as an example) is part of the `textcolor` plugin:

```
editor.addButton('forecolor', {
    type: 'colorbutton',
    tooltip: 'Text color',
    format: 'forecolor',
    panel: {
        role: 'application',
        ariaRemember: true,
        html: renderColorPicker,
        onclick: onPanelClick
    },
    onclick: onButtonClick
});
```

As TinyMCE is open source you can certainly adjust where controls are added.  If you look at the `print` plugin you will see an example of a plugin adding an item to a Menu as opposed to a toolbar.

You could modify the plugins and the tinymce.js file to do what you are after but keep in mind you would then need to manage these changes when you update TinyMCE in the future.

Comment: So basically there is no "easy" way. This seems like a real gap in the functionality. Oh well.